# Prove that $3+ 3\cdot5+...+3\cdot5^n = \frac{3(5^{n+1}-1)}{4}$ for all nonnegative integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have been stuck on this one for a while. Supposed to use induction to prove that $3+ 3\cdot5+...+3\cdot5^n = \Large\frac{3(5^{n+1}-1)}{4}$ for all nonegative integers.

I don't know if I'm taking the wrong steps but I can't get past

$P(k+1) = \Large\frac{3((5^{n+1}-1)+4(5^{n+1}))}{4}$

Comment: $3\cdot 5^{n+1}+12\cdot 5^{n+1}= 15\cdot 5^{n+1}=3\cdot 5^{n+2}$. Or more simply $5^{n+1}+4\cdot 5^{n+1}=5\cdot 5^{n+1}=5^{n+2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  The next step is to combine like terms.

$$5^{n+1}+4(5^{n+1})=(1+4)5^{n+1}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Just came back to answer my own question, thank you anyways. It won't let me accept an answer for a few minutes (not sure why) but I'll be back.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Forget momentarily the $3$ it's just a factor and prove by induction that
$$1+5+5^2+\cdots+5^n=\frac{5^{n+1}-1}{4} $$

*Inductive step:*

$$1+5+5^2+\cdots+5^n+5^{n+1}=\frac{5^{n+1}-1}{4}+ 5^{n+1}=\frac{5^{n+2}-1}{4}$$

Comment: Excellent hint, Sami!

Answer (score 0):

If
$$3+3\cdot5+...+3\cdot5^n=\frac{3(5^{n+1}-1)}{4}\iff 1+5+...+5^n=\frac{5^{n+1}-1}{4}$$
then
$$1+5+...+5^n+5^{n+1}=\frac{5^{n+1}-1}{4}+5^{n+1}=$$
$$=\frac{5^{n+1}-1+4\cdot5^{n+1}}{4}=\frac{5\cdot5^{n+1}-1}{4}=\frac{5^{(n+1)+1}-1}{4}$$